# What's a quantum algorithm in the black box model to find $j_1,j_2$ such that $f(x_1,...,x_n)=x_{j1}\oplus x_{j2}$?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-circuit, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

Consider the set of all functions $f : \{0, 1\}^n → \{0, 1\}$ that are of the form $f(x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n) = x_{j1}\oplus x_{j2}$
for some distinct $j_1, j_2 \in \{1, 2, . . . , n\}$. Suppose that we are given such a function as a black box without any information on $j_1$ and $j_2$. But we want to determine $j_1, j_2$ with certainty using a quantum circuit.

Can you give a quantum algorithm in the black box model that solves this problem with a single query to the black box of $f$?

Comment: Why do you mention Deutsch-Jozsa in the question title? (I'm guessing this is a homework question and you know, at least from context, that Deutsch-Jozsa is associated.) Have you tried apply the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm to this particular function? (Show us your working)